Why ingress objects are namespaced resources?
Namespaced resources should be unique within the namespace, but not necessarily across the namespace. A same ingress rule (hostname + path) cannot exist twice within a namespace or even across the namespace.
In a multi-tenant cluster architecture, where teams manage their own workloads, how can an ingress rule be configured without knowing if it is available to use. The team might need to know all hostname and path which are already in use.
And can I have more than one default backend? How does it work?

Consider to use the newer Gateway API that solves these problems: https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/
